# Is this a valid way to check if db_row exists?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I am working with Zend and I needed to check whether a row in the DB already exists (A simple solution to get rid of the duplicate key error I was getting). I tried several things but nothing seemed to work... (for example the **Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists** method)

So I wrote the following the code and I was wondering if this is a valid way to do it, or if I should do things differently:

In the model:

```
 $where =  $condition = array(
        'user_id = ' . $user_id,
        'page_id = ' . $page_id
        );

        $check = $this->fetchRow($where);

        if(count($check) > 0) {

            return null;

        }else{
              // Here I create a new row, fill it with data, save and return it.
        }
```

And then in my view:

```
 if($this->result != null) { /* do stuff */  }else{ /* do other stuff */ }
```

It does work but it does seem to take more time (duh, because of the extra query) and I am a bit unsure whether I should stick with this..

Any recommendation is welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have coded your function in your controller

```
$row = $this->fetchRow($where);   //If no row is found then $row is null .

    if(!$row)
    {
    $row = $dbTb->createNew($insert); //$insert an associative array where it keys map cols of table
    $row->save();
     $this->view->row_not_found = true;
    }

    return $row;
```

In your view you can do this

```
if($this->row_not_found)
{
}else {

}
```

Comment: Ah! I forgot the fetch method automatically returns null if no row is found. The method I use for inserting new data is via `$row = $this->createRow` and then ` if($row) { $row->user_id = $user_id.. etc.` Thank you though!

Comment: BUT! wait.. now $row always returns with a value.. I need it to return NULL if the row **already** exists because that's what I need to know in my view! I added an  `}else{ return null` , works like a charm.